# Roulette wheel probability question

Tags: probability

A roulette wheel has $21$ red numbers, $21$ black numbers, and $4$ zeros. A player places $20$ dollar bets on the red numbers. If the roulette spins a red number, the player get his $20$ dollars back, and wins another $20$ dollars. If the roulette does not spin a red number, the player loses his bet. The player sits down with $40$ dollars, and keeps on playing until he has no more money. How many spins can he expect to be able to play until he has no more money?

Comment: Related: [roulette probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396921/roulette-probabilty/2397014#2397014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first calculate the expected winnings of each round.

He will win \$$20$ with probability $21/(21+21+4)$ and win -\$$20$ (that is, lose \$$20$) with proability $(21+4)/(21+21+4)$. Therefore his expected winnings per round is:
$$
E:=20\left(\frac{21}{21+21+4}\right) - 20\left(\frac{21+4}{21+21+4}\right)
= -\frac{80}{46} = -\frac{40}{23}.
$$
Given that he starts with \$$40$, this means that he can expect to play $40/(-E)=23$ rounds.

Comment: I think you'll find that if you don't round in the first step that you'll get an answer of *exactly* $23$.

Comment: As an aside, this answer agrees with [a direct calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+(2n*(2n+choose+n)%2F(n%2B1)*(21%5E(n-1)25%5E(n%2B1))%2F46%5E(2n))) as well but skips the necessity of figuring out the pdf and evaluating the sum.

Comment: @JMoravitz Indeed!